# how to add new Headers to .csv file?

Tags: c#, csv

I am writing three variables in a (.csv) file with time dynamically, I want add Headers to these three variables. My code is ..

```
   private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      string dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh.mm.ss.ffffff");
      StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(NameYourFile.Text + DateTime.Today.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy") + ".csv");
      string var =(dt) + ',' + adsClient.ReadAny(hActVel, typeof(double)).ToString() + ',' + adsClient.ReadAny(hSActVel, typeof(double)).ToString();
      string[] lines = 
          foreach (string line in lines)
          {
             if(line == lines[0])
             {
                writer.WriteLine( string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", "Time", "Big Motor Actual Velocity", "Small Motor Actual Velocity"));
             }

          }
     writer.WriteLine(var);
     writer.Dispose();
   }
```

Thank you

Comment: Move the header outside the foreach and the `writer.WriteLine(var);` inside the foreach and what happens?

Comment: please tell me what should i write for   string[] lines =

Comment: Without knowing where you data comes from it would be hard.

Comment: i am reading data from adsclient(the ads client is an external hardware) and just i want to write that data to .c s v file

Comment: writing to .c s v is done but i need to include headers to that data columns in .c s v file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class adsClientEntry
{
    public DateTime EntryTime;
    public double BigMotorVelocity;
    public double SmallMotorVelocity;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    CreateFile();
}

public void CreateFile()
{
    string path = YourFileName.Text + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy") + ".csv";
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
    {
        // Create file if no Exists
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", "Time", "Big Motor Actual Velocity", "Small Motor Actual Velocity"));          
        }
    }

}

private void AppendLog(adsClientEntry thisEntry)
{
    string path = YourFileName.Text + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy") + ".csv";
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(string.Format(
            "{0},{1},{2}", 
            thisEntry.EntryTime.ToString("hh.mm.ss.ffffff"), 
            thisEntry.BigMotorVelocity.ToString(),
            thisEntry.SmallMotorVelocity.ToString()
            ));
    }

}

private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    adsClientEntry thisEntry = new adsClientEntry();
    thisEntry.EntryTime = DateTime.Now();
    thisEntry.BigMotorVelocity = adsClient.ReadAny(hActVel, typeof(double));
    thisEntry.SmallMotorVelocity = adsClient.ReadAny(hSActVel, typeof(double));

    AppendLog(thisEntry);        

}
```